# Why my grid doesn't work in Chrome but, does in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: html, css

I have a project that I'm working on and I use CSS grids to style it as I want. The problem is sometimes it works in Chrome and sometimes it doesn't

Look at screenshot and below it is the code:-

The screenshots are at the same zoom level and the same pixel ratio, and the same pixel size!
This is the navigation in Google Chrome made with the grid system

[image: A weird blue space in the right of my navigation in Chrome]

And this is the navigation in Firefox Developer Edition made with the grid system

[image: The same navigation if Firefox but there is no blue space]

And here is my code

`HTML`

```html
<!-- START: GRID CONTAINER -->
    <div class="l-grid">
      <!-- START: RESPONSIVE NAVBAR -->
      <nav class="l-navigation" data-screen="mini">
        <div class="l-navigation__cart js-miniCartTrigger" data-icon="miniCart">
          <a href="#" class="l-navigation--cart--focus"
            ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart l-navigation__cart--icon"></i
          ></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Make the whole div a hyperlink -->
        <!-- Remember to remove this element when using the mini cart because it's clickable even when its beneath it -->
        <div
          class="l-navigation__logo"
          onclick="location.href='http:/\/localhost:5500/index.html'"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-gem l-navigation__logo--icon"></i>
          <h2 class="l-navigation__logo--title">The H</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="l-navigation__menu" data-menu="miniMenu">
          <a href="#" class="l-navigation--menu--focus"
            ><i class="fas fa-bars l-navigation__menu--icon js-navigationIcon"></i
          ></a>
            <i class="fas fa-times l-navigation__menu--icon u-d-none js-navigationIconCancel"></i
          ></a>
        </div>
        <!-- END: RESPONSIVE NAVBAR -->
      </nav>
       <!-- END: GRID -->
     </div>
```

`CSS` for the grid

```
.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 7rem;
  gap: 0.3rem;
  grid-template-areas: "navigation";
}
```

`CSS` for the navigation

```
.l-navigation {
  grid-area: navigation;
  background-color: $color-navigation-bar;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $color-navigation-border;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong here? And if possible can you tell me how can I make the grid system suitable for mobile-first designing?

Thanks

Comment: Lol,  I forgot to remove a comment but I won't now because it's funny. The comment (Remember to remove this element...etc) is something for me not for the post sorry! You can ignore it

Comment: Hi. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Dejan.S Why do I have this weird space in my navigation when using the grid system in Chrome but I don't have it in Firefox? Do you know why? Or how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my question

Well, the problem is not something with the code but actually with Google Chrome So I'm keeping it here for others to see and find the answer

If you restart your computer or remove the cache it works great and it doesn't have anything to do with the code itself

Well, actually if you just resize the window without going to the responsive panel in the inspect element tool in Chrome it works

I found the answer for this stupid and silly thing after 2 hours of wasting time here and there